# Django: Save user-submitted data from ModelForm for admin review and committing at a later date

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form on my Django site (made with ModelForm) where users can submit some data to create new objects or modify existing objects.  These data, however, need to be reviewed by our staff before they're committed to the database, sometimes in bulk at a later date.

I know I can use `.save(commit=False)` in my form-processing view to return an object that has not been saved to the database yet. But is there a way to collect all of these objects from multiple user submissions for later review?  Ideally, I'd have an admin page that had a summary list of submissions with "Commit" or "Reject" buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no one-step-out-of-the-box way to do this (at least not built in to Django), so you'll need to create the logic yourself, which should be pretty straightforward. Some approaches to consider:

1. Have a second model/table to which your form saves, then create a view for the review functionality which copies any approved records into the first table.
2. Avoid having second model/table and add a `approved = BoolField(default=False)` field to your model/table. Set `objects` to a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) which filters for `default=True` so the rest of your code will only see approved records by default. Have a second manager that does the opposite, i.e. filtering for unapproved records. Using this second manager, create a view for the review functionality which flips `approved` to `True` for anything that gets approved.
3. If, with the second approach above, you want use Django's admin site to do the review, create a [proxy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for your model which by default uses the second manager which filters for unapproved records. Then you can use the admin's inline display and editing functionality to see records at a glance and click approve as needed.

Comment: These are sort of the ideas I had in mind.  The problem with #2/3 is how this could be done for modified objects (though it would be straightforward for new objects only).  The only problem with #1 is the duplication, but I think that's the way I'll go.  (There's also **[this](https://github.com/dominno/django-moderation)** which may do what I'm asking.)

Comment: @Danos2000, that `django-moderation` app looks very interesting. It seems to be a souped-up, nicely packaged, and configurable version of approach 1, using a separate table to save unapproved objects and copying them over to the actual table when approved.

Comment: @Danos2000, if you do want to roll your own, to deal with changed objects, you might try something like `django-dirtyfields` in `save()` to see if anything has changed, and if so flip the approved status back to `False` (for approaches 2/3) or move the record back to the unapproved table (for approach 1). You can also implement analogous on-change logic at the form level ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710845/in-django-1-4-do-form-has-changed-and-form-changed-data-which-are-undocument/11954195#11954195) can be useful) if that suits your situation better.