# Django/Forms: How can i validate initial data against received data (if match)?

Tags: django, django-forms, hidden-field, code-access-security, django-models

Let's say that I'm creating a form and I'm passing some hidden values through bound, that must not be changed. My question is how can I test if a malicious user has changed this hidden values?
I'm not sure what exactly does bound data in a form and the difference between initial.

In the Django's [forms.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3/django/forms/forms.py) is a property called [changed_data](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3/django/forms/forms.py#L322) but I don't know if can help or not.

Code for demonstration:

**forms.py**

```
class ConfirmForm(forms.Form):
    client_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    identifier = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean(self):
        # Maybe here the validation process of cliend_id and identifier like:
        clean_client_id = self.cleaned_data.get('client_id')
        clean_identifier = self.cleaned_data.get('identifier')
        if last_client_id == clean_client_id and 
           last_identifier == clean_identifier:
            return self.cleaned_data
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("False data.")
```

**views.py**

```
def form_confirm_handler(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConfirmForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Do something...
            return redirect('home:index')

    #The following values are not fixed. Are generated variables!
    bound_data = {'client_id':'123456','identifier':'wuiy5895'}
    form = ConfirmForm(bound_data)
    return render(request, 'client/theform.html', {'form':form})
```

**html template**

```
<form action="{% url 'client:confirm' %}" method="post">
    <p>Do you really want to proceed?</p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.client_id }}
    {{ form.identifier }}
    <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="accept">Accept</button>
    <button id="cancel" type="submit" name="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not create a hidden field for initial value?

Comment: sorry, i don't get it, client_id and identifier are already hidden fields for that purpose.

Comment: have a look at this [QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710845/in-django-1-4-do-form-has-changed-and-form-changed-data-which-are-undocument)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found 4 (easy) possible solutions to this problem.

The most valid solution for Django is this:

```
class TheFormName():
    client_id = forms.CharField(show_hidden_initial=True, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    identifier = forms.CharField(show_hidden_initial=True, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

def clean(self):
    if self.has_changed():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Fields are not valid.')

    return self.cleaned_data
```

The second solution is by using the `changed_data` to see what has changed:

```
def clean(self):
    for field_name in self.changed_data:
        # loop through the fields which have changed
        print "field {} has changed. New value {}".format(field_name, cleaned_data['field_name']
```

For my case is translated to this, but is exactly the same as the `has_changed()` method:

```
def clean(self):
    if len(self.changed_data) > 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Fields are not valid.')

    return self.cleaned_data
```

Another solution that looks more like a hack is:

```
self.cleaned_data['cliend_id'] == self.instance.cliend_id
self.cleaned_data['identifier'] == self.instance.identifier
```

And the final solution a bit more complex is by using sessions inside `clean()` method (and outside of view). Example from [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views):

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
import datetime
s = SessionStore()
s['last_login'] = datetime.datetime(2005, 8, 20, 13, 35, 10)
s.save()
s.session_key
>>> '2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead'

s = SessionStore(session_key='2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead')
s['last_login']
```

Also useful is this post [In Django 1.4, do Form.has_changed() and Form.changed_data, which are undocumented, work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710845/in-django-1-4-do-form-has-changed-and-form-changed-data-which-are-undocument) provided by @LarsVegas

Answer (score 0):

Create a new hidden field called `temper_seal`

```
temper_seal = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

Set the initial value of `temper_seal` to a hash of `client_id` and `identifier` and some random constant string only known to your server.

When the form comes back with user data, hash the values of `client_id` and `identifier` and the constant string used earlier. Compare this value to the value submitted in the hidden `temper_seal` field. If they are the same, the user did not change the data in `client_id` and `identifier`.

Comment: The idea is not to be fixed string. I don't know the previous "generated" value

Comment: @JorgeCode Everything client-side can be modified by the user. If the server does not know the original data beforehand, I don't think there's anything you can do to check validity.

Comment: Yes that's the idea. For example. I generate an identifier (let's say a number), so i want this number to be remembered somehow by the server and then when the user submit's the form the server validates the data against the original data. I don't know the part of how the server will "remember" the original data.

Comment: You can do a few things if the intitial value is generated by the server. One obvious one is to write it to the database. Then compare it to the receive value. Another is to send a hash of the initial value and some secret only know on your server to the client and store it in another hidden field. When the values come back, hash the value from the first hidden field concatenated with your server secret and compare it to the hash stored in your second hidden field. If same, nothing changed. Otherwise, it was tempered with. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I been thinking if you can use a session variables.

```
def form_confirm_handler(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConfirmForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            if form.cleaned_data.get['client_id'] == request.session.get('client_id'):
                //.....
            else:
                //.....

            //delete the session after comparing
            del request.session['client_id']
            del request.session['identifier']

            return redirect('home:index')

    #The following values are not fixed. Are generated variables!

    request.session['client_id'] = '123456'
    request.session['identifier'] = 'wuiy5895'

    bound_data = {
        'client_id': request.session.get('client_id'), 
        'identifier': request.session.get('identifier')
    }

    form = ConfirmForm(bound_data)
    return render(request, 'client/theform.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Thank you catherine indeed is working your example but i was thinking a more elegant solution. All the validation checks should be done inside clean().

Comment: That's the first one I think. Don't worry If I can think another, I will post it here. Hmmmmm... I've thinking something I don't know if it's working, need to test it

Comment: your number 2 solution I already seen that but I don't know how to use it. `changed_data` and `has_changed`