# Django pass initial values from object in Model Form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have django model form `MyModelFormA` for the model `ModelA` (I am using these in `FormView`).

I want to pass initial values to the form using existing object of `ModelA` and create new object of it if changes occur.

I have been passing initial values like below:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(MyFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'instance': ModelAObject})
```

I'm not sure why but when the form is validated like below

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save()
```

Its just updating existing `instance` object instead of creating new.

1. HTTP requests being stateless, how does the request knows an `instance` that is being passed processed in previous request
2. How to solve this?

I thought of doing something like

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = model_to_dict(MyModelAObject)
    return initial
```

Actually There are only a subset of `MyModelA` fields in `MyModelFormA`. Passing all fields as dict initially, wouldn't create any trouble?

is there any much elegant way to handle it?

Comment: How do you get `ModelAObject`?

Comment: I get it from database! `ModelA.objects.get()`

Comment: But how do you get some particular object?

Comment: well, the url endpoint is something like `/pk/edit`. So, I get the object from there which I evaluate in `dispatch()`

Answer (score 1):

1. When you pass **ModelForm an instance**, it sets id field of that instance as initial of the form as well. So, if it receives an ID in the POST, its treats it as a existing object and updates it
2. You will need to pass individual field's initial value(i.e except id). The **best way** is to only pass the **fields you need**, in ModelForm, as initial.

> ```
> def get_initial(self):
>   return {
>       'a': MyModelAObject.a,
>       ....
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.has_changed()
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.pk = None
        #if you have id 
        instance.id = None
        instance.save() #will give you new instance.
```

Check [In Django 1.4, do Form.has_changed() and Form.changed_data, which are undocumented, work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710845/in-django-1-4-do-form-has-changed-and-form-changed-data-which-are-undocument) to see how `form.has_changed()` will work.

Comment: If the form passes `pk` value to the template as hidden field, isn't that create security loop holes? For instance, users can go and edit pk value and make the form believe it comes from wrong object!!